# Lighttpd escapes <?php ?> in served html files?

Tags: php, lighttpd

I'm working on a lighttpd server in an embedded system that is not configured by me. I use Google Chrome to see the source code for the HTML files.
I don't know what's wrong but when I request the following simple file:

**Note: the file extension is .html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
Hello world!
<?php echo "PHP commands"?>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives the following file to my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
Hello world!
<!--?php echo "PHP commands"?-->
</body>
</html>
```

In other words it comments out the php commands disabling them! Why? How can I solve it? Couldn't find anything wrong in the config files.

**Even though it is not saved in a file with .php extension, I want lighttpd to ignore the php commands inside the html. I know it's not a valid HTML, but I want it to be untouched.**

Comment: Is PHP installed on the server and lighttpd configured correctly to work with it, via FastCGI or something similar?

Comment: Yeah it's installed and fastcgi is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that:

1. The embedded system does not have a working PHP interpreter or is not configured for the file extension you are using.
2. You are inspecting the HTML code through a browser tool (Firebug or something) that's not showing the *original* HTML but the *generated* HTML. Since `<?php ... ?>` is not a valid HTML tag, it's converted to a (valid) comment.

Comment: the file is saved as HTML not PHP. When I save it as PHP it works fine. For this specific project I need to have it saved as HTML. The question is: how can I force lighttpd to leave the file with PHP commands inside it untouched?

Comment: Your second guess was true. I was using Chrome. When I used IE8 it showed the original source code to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain, and I found that only "fix" is to give your files an extension of **.php**, which many people aren't keen to do..